# What is a USB Host Device?

Tags: usb, usb-device

I recently came across the term USB Host Device while reading how someone used a micro controller as a USB Host device.I haven't been able to understand the meaning of this term.

- Could some one please tell me what it is in the simplest words possible?

Also

- how is it different from a USB peripheral device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A host device is a computing device into which you can plug a peripheral.

Some micros can be either a host or a peripheral.  Using the mouse as an example:  If your micro is emulating a mouse and plugged into a computer, it is a peripheral.  If your micro is accepting input from a mouse (and presumably acting on it in some way), then your micro is a host device, capable of hosting a plugged in peripheral.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: The mouse is a bad example; no mouse is a USB host.

Comment: The mouse's relationship to the microcontroller was the example.  If the micro IS the mouse, it is a peripheral.  If the micro is CONNECTED to a mouse, it is a host

Comment: And yes, I'm sure I worded it poorly.